# How to fix DynamoDB JS API blocking and timing out my Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm attempting to access AWS DynamoDB from a Lambda function. When I call the document client's scan function using a promise, it never returns even when I extend the function's timeout to a whole minute.

I'm using Serverless platform, Node 8.10, and I've set up the "iamRoleStatements" to allow dynamodb and the table's ARN.

serverless.yml:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  timeout: 6
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:*
      Resource: "[arn from dynamodb]"
```

handler.js:

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
...
...
...
    try {
      console.log('dynamodb go')
      attributes = await dynamodb.scan(queryParams).promise()
      console.log('dynamodb success')
      console.log(attributes)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('dynamodb error')
    }
```

I'm expecting to get "dynamodb go" then "dynamodb success" or even "dynamodb error" in the console. However, after printing "dynamodb go" the function hangs and ends up timing out. Am I doing the promise wrong somehow? It seems like this should be the correct format based on what I've seen.

Comment: Did you try something simpler and quicker like describeTable() to make sure that you actually have connectivity to DynamoDB?

Comment: @jarmod I describeTable() and that seems to time out too. For describeTable() I just used the base AWS.DynamoDB object instead of the document client, that's correct, right?

Comment: I edited my post with the creation of my documentclient object. Is there any configuration that I need to do to get this working? The Lambda function is being called from an authenticated request from a web client with a cognito identity.

Comment: is your Lambda running in a VPC?

Comment: Any connectivity timeout like this is typically because your Lambda function cannot reach the network resource that it's trying to connect to, in this case DynamoDB. That typically is caused by one thing - you are running the Lambda function in a private subnet of a VPC and that subnet has no viable route to the internet or to DynamoDB via a VPC Endpoint. Could that be what's happening here?

Comment: @jarmod It's almost definitely that actually. I struggled with getting the function to connect to an RDS instance and I'm not really sure exactly what I did. I don't really understand how VPCs work and I'm not sure how to add the DynamoDB instance to the VPC. Can you recommend a resource on that?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Lambda function cannot connect to DynamoDB. That typically is caused by one thing - you are running the Lambda function in a VPC and the Lambda function has no viable route to DynamoDB (either over the public internet or to DynamoDB via a private VPC Endpoint).

Presumably you're running your Lambda function inside a VPC so that it can access your private RDS database, which would not otherwise be reachable over the public internet.

You have a couple of choices:

1. [give the Lambda function internet access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html#vpc-internet) so it can reach DynamoDB over the public internet
2. add a [VPC Endpoint for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html) to the VPC so it can reach DynamoDB privately

Note that both are over TLS so are secure. The decision is whether or not to allow the Lambda function to have unfettered outbound internet access (#1), or to constrain it to DynamoDB (#2).

Comment: I'll try this soon and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Do I really need to make a whole EC2 instance just to get these two services to talk to each other? I feel kind of frustrated with how Serverless computing was supposed to help me by taking care of all these tasks for me but then it creates all these new challenges which are new to me.

Comment: Update: Decided to just get rid of the VPC and instead I'll try to make the RDS instance publicly accessible. Just makes everything easier.

Comment: @danielhep Exposing an RDBMS to the public internet is rarely a good idea. You should be able to give Lambda access to both your private RDS instance and the DynamoDB service without the need for a NAT gateway or public internet access. Did you try this with a VPC endpoint for DynamoDB?